# How to update something in main class in thread

Tags: java, android, url

Hi I am trying to make a multiplayer game where it would find the opponent in another thread, but I am not sure why the code running in the thread does not update the model in the main class...

Here is the code in the main class. The call to the LoadTask starts another thread

```
// Start model, passing number of words, user name, and selected animal
        model = new MultiPlayerModel(NUM_WORDS, username, anmID);
        model.addObserver(this);

        new LoadTask().execute();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_multi_player);
        initialDisplay(animal, background, oppAnimal);
```

Here is the code for the thread class

```
    private class LoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        // called before running code in a separate thread
        private boolean quitFlag;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MultiPlayer.this,"Finding a Game...",  
                    "Searching for opponent, please wait...", false, false);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    model.beginMatchMaking();
                    model.setWordsList();
                    // Get the opponent's animal from the model
                    oppAnimal = reverseDrawable(model.getOpponentAnimal());
                    // Display the multiplayer screen

                } catch (InternetConnectionException e) {
                    e.fillInStackTrace();
                    quitFlag = true;
                    error(States.error.CONNECTION);
                    return null;
                } catch (EmptyQueueException e) {
                    e.fillInStackTrace();
                    quitFlag = true;
                    error(States.error.NOOPPONENT);
                    return null;
                } catch (InternalErrorException e) {
                    e.fillInStackTrace();
                    quitFlag = true;
                    error(States.error.INTERNAL);
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if (!quitFlag) {
              progressDialog.dismiss();
              gameTimer = new GameTimer(START_TIME, INTERVAL);
              gameTimer.start();
            }
        }
    }
```

And it segfaults on initialDisplay after the thread is called because the fields in model class were not updated at all. it acts as though it was just created and nothing was done to it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about AsyncTask class 
but if it's properly configurated Thread and next line

```
new LoadTask().execute();
```

will start this thread properly, in this case thread will execute inparallel but usualy after lines:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_multi_player);
initialDisplay(animal, background, oppAnimal);
```

to prove it you may print messages main methods.
To solve it you may simply add next line after starting thread:

```
new LoadTask().execute();
Thread.sleep(100)
```

Comment: O ok so your saying that it doesn't work because the are running in parallel so it might not get the the main class before it updates in the thread. is there anyway to make the main thread wait until the other one finishes?

Comment: well the simplest way is don't use thread if you need just wait until it finished - use simple method call.
But in common case you may use monitor/wait/notify or CountDownLatch approach

Comment: so the reason why I need to do it in a thread is because I want it to show a progress bar that it is waiting instead of a black screen.  Even if i do the Thread.sleep(100) and the CountDownLatch it still segfaults... any ideas